# Python pass arguments from a .csv file to threads

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

the csv:

```
email,password
test0@test.com,SuperSecretpassword123!
test1@test.com,SuperSecretpassword123!
test2@test.com,SuperSecretpassword123!
test3@test.com,SuperSecretpassword123!
```

the example printing function

```
def start_printer(row):
    email = row["email"]
    password = row["password"]

    print(f"{email}:{password}")
```

the threading starting example

```
                number_of_threads = 10

                for _ in range(number_of_threads):
                    t = Thread(target=start_printer, args=(row,))
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    t.start()
                    threads.append(t)
                for t in threads:
                    t.join()
```

how do I pass the values from the csv to the threading example?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Opening the csv file? Passing it to `csv.reader`? Looping over the rows?

Comment: i have problems initializing the whole logic ...

Comment: like passing the arguments from the csv to the threading ...

Comment: What have you tried? If you have trouble opening a file for example, write a question specifically about that - currently your question comes down to "please write this for me" and that's not what SO is for. If you have solved part of the problem, but just have a problem with this part, please share the code you have so far to solve the problem.

Comment: I think the whole problem is my understanding with threading it has nothing to do with like "can you do it for me" I really don't understand how to pass the arguments to the threading

Comment: You have `args=(row,)` right there, and as the documentation states ["args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ()"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) - you'll need to provide a more complete example and explain what is not work, or what you're assiging to `row`

Comment: yeah this is absolutely clear for me but how to pass each line of a csv parallel to a thread ... I've posted how I read the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could go about it this way:

```
from threading import Thread
from csv import DictReader

def returnPartionedList(inputlist: list, x: int = 100) -> list: # returns inputlist split into x parts, default is 100
    return([inputlist[i:i + x] for i in range(0, len(inputlist), x)])

def start_printer(row) -> None:
    email: str = row["email"]
    password: str = row["password"]
    print(f"{email}:{password}")

def main() -> None:
    path: str = r"tasks.csv"
    list_tasks: list = []
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        csv_reader: DictReader = DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            list_tasks.append(row)
    list_tasks_partitions: list = returnPartionedList(list_tasks, 10) # Run 10 threads per partition
    for partition in list_tasks_partitions:
        threads: list = [Thread(target=start_printer, args=(row,)) for row in partition]
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
            t.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
test0@test.com:SuperSecretpassword123!
test1@test.com:SuperSecretpassword123!
test2@test.com:SuperSecretpassword123!
test3@test.com:SuperSecretpassword123!
```